# For loop select specific part of string variable

Tags: linux, bash, loops, unix, posix

simple question:
I have a variable called x:

```
echo $x
3122;192.31.231.2 3379;183.3.202.111 3085;218.25.208.92
```

What I would like is to iterate over the IP's only, not the initial number.

```
192.31.231.2
183.3.202.111
218.25.208.92
```

Current code:

```
for ip in $x; 
do
    echo `geoiplookup "$ip[$2]"`
done
```

Answer (score 4):

One idea using [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html):

```
x="3122;192.31.231.2 3379;183.3.202.111 3085;218.25.208.92"

for stuff in ${x}                 # process each '<number>;ip' pair separately
do
    ip="${stuff##*;}"             # strip off leading '<number>;'
    echo "${ip}"
    # geoiplookup "${ip}"
done
```

**NOTE**: I'm not familiar with the `geoiplookup` command so not sure why OP is wrapping the `geoiplookup` call inside an `echo` call versus just calling `geoiplookup` directly ... ??

This generates:

```
192.31.231.2
183.3.202.111
218.25.208.92
```

From here the OP can reference `${ip}` as needed for the `geoiplookup` call.

Comment: could you explain your ans?

Comment: [From what I could find](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hirsute/man1/geoiplookup.1.html), `geoiplookup <ip|hostname>` results in a single line of output like `NL, Netherlands`. The `echo` is consequently unnecessary.

Answer (score 3):

If we can assume, that between each number and IP address is a semicolon, then we just need to cut until delimiter (i.e. `;` in this case) and select second part.

We can do it in such manner: `echo $var | cut -d';' -f2`

Now to put this back into your code:

```sh
for ip in $x; do
    geoiplookup "$(echo $ip | cut -d';' -f2)"
    # wrapping it in `echo` would just print what would be printed either way
done
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this Perl one-liner, connected to a `while` loop via a pipe:

```
perl -lne 'print for /\b\d+;([\d.]+)\b/g' <<<$x | \
    while read -r ip ; do
        echo "my_command ${ip}"
    done
```

The Perl one-liner uses these command line flags:
`-e` : Tells Perl to look for code in-line, instead of in a file.
`-n` : Loop over the input one line at a time, assigning it to `$_` by default.
`-l` : Strip the input line separator (`"\n"` on *NIX by default) before executing the code in-line, and append it when printing.

`/\b\d+;([\d.]+)\b/g` - Captures and returns IP addresses. Returns multiple matches (regex `/g` modifier). Matches `\b` - a word boundary, followed by `\d+;` -  a stretch of digits ending with a semicolon, followed by `[\d.]+` - a stretch of digits or periods, followed by `\b` - another word boundary.